# can't set constraint layout with scrollView

Tags: java, android, xml, android-layout, layout

I am trying since 2 days ago to create this simple layout: [image] it is not exactly equal, but it is near that what I want.

When I try to set the scrollView on my constraint layout I get always this messy

[image: view]

even if I constraint all my elements, I don't know how to organize the things at the moment, I am really confused about this.

**here is my xml:**

```
<ScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    tools:context=".PhotosForPlant">

    <android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
        xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        tools:context="com.example.afcosta.inesctec.pt.android.PhotosForPlant"
        tools:layout_editor_absoluteX="0dp"
        tools:layout_editor_absoluteY="0dp">

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/plantImage"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            app:srcCompat="@drawable/color_cursor_white"
            tools:layout_editor_absoluteX="16dp"
            tools:layout_editor_absoluteY="41dp" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/descricaoTit"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Descrição"
            tools:layout_editor_absoluteX="0dp"
            tools:layout_editor_absoluteY="582dp" />


        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/specieDescription"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="TextView"
            tools:layout_editor_absoluteX="4dp"
            tools:layout_editor_absoluteY="622dp" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/Family"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Familia"
            tools:layout_editor_absoluteX="16dp"
            tools:layout_editor_absoluteY="458dp" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textView7"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Genre"
            tools:layout_editor_absoluteX="24dp"
            tools:layout_editor_absoluteY="389dp" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textView8"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Espécie"
            tools:layout_editor_absoluteX="16dp"
            tools:layout_editor_absoluteY="309dp" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/FamilyName"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            tools:layout_editor_absoluteX="96dp"
            tools:layout_editor_absoluteY="458dp" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/GenreName"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            tools:layout_editor_absoluteX="96dp"
            tools:layout_editor_absoluteY="389dp" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/SpecieName"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            tools:layout_editor_absoluteX="96dp"
            tools:layout_editor_absoluteY="309dp" />

        <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
            android:id="@+id/gallery"
            android:layout_width="408dp"
            android:layout_height="111dp"
            tools:layout_editor_absoluteX="0dp"
            tools:layout_editor_absoluteY="141dp" />
    </android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
</ScrollView>
```

Comment: Use NestedScrollView  instead of ScrollView.

Comment: can you give me a example?

Comment: i just need 1 scroll, why nested?

Comment: Refer this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43098150/android-how-to-make-a-scrollable-constraintlayout probably you may get solution

Comment: i don't see any constraints in your layout of u not set constraint to views they will not positioned right go through this https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/constraint/ConstraintLayout.html

Comment: i can't set the constaints, dunno why1

Comment: if u are not able through ui editor u can do it in manually go through link u will get an idea

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As per your requirement i created sample layout so you can design same according to that i used nestedscrollview rather than scrollview and also applied constraint for all views

```
   <android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:fillViewport="true"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        tools:context="com.example.afcosta.inesctec.pt.android.PhotosForPlant"
        tools:layout_editor_absoluteX="0dp"
        tools:layout_editor_absoluteY="0dp">

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/plantImage"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            app:srcCompat="@drawable/smile"
            app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
            android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
            android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
            app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.573"
            android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/toolbar2" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textView3"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="TextViLeft"
            app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
            android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/plantImage"
            android:layout_marginStart="8dp" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textView5"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="TextViewDetail1"
            app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
            android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/textView3"
            android:layout_marginStart="8dp" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textView6"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="TextViewDetail2"
            app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
            android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/textView13" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textView7"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="TextViewDetail3"
            app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
            android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/textView14" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textView12"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="TextView"
            app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
            android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/plantImage"
            android:layout_marginEnd="8dp" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textView13"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="TextViewBold1"
            android:textStyle="bold"
            android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/textView3"
            app:layout_constraintLeft_toRightOf="@+id/textView5"
            android:layout_marginStart="20dp" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textView14"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="TextViewBold2"
            android:textStyle="bold"
            app:layout_constraintLeft_toRightOf="@+id/textView6"
            android:layout_marginStart="20dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/textView13" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textView15"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="TextViewBold3"
            app:layout_constraintLeft_toRightOf="@+id/textView7"
            android:textStyle="bold"
            android:layout_marginStart="20dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/textView14" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textView16"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="TextView TextView TextView TextView TextViewTextViewTextViewTextViewTextViewTextViewTextViewTextViewTextViewTextViewTextViewTextViewTextViewTextViewTextViewTextViewTextViewTextViewTextView"

            app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
            android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
            android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
            app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.0"
            android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/textView15" />

        <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_margin="8dp"
            android:id="@+id/recyclerview"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/textView16"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            tools:layout_editor_absoluteX="8dp" />

        <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
            android:id="@+id/toolbar2"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
            android:minHeight="?attr/actionBarSize"
            android:theme="?attr/actionBarTheme"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent" />


    </android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
</android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView>
```

here is design and blue print

[image]
**NOTE:** You are using RecyclerView in ScrollView which is not recommended.

Comment: i want to change my layout to nested so i can use the toolbar, but it doesn't work

Comment: what is the problem u getting?

Comment: cant set the constraint i changed all android to app, but not working :S

Comment: where u want toolbar in existing xml layout or any other? post that xml where u trying to set toolbar

Comment: in the existing, i couldn't change to the nested scroll as you have :/

Comment: now updated answer with toolbar u have to set theme no actionbar and set this toolbar runtime as action bar check edited xml code in answer

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/145897/discussion-between-pavan-and-filipe-costa).