# Why does my ScrollView cut off after an imageView is added?

Tags: android, android-layout, android-imageview, android-scrollview, android-constraintlayout

When I try to add an imageView programmatically to the scrollView the bottom image gets cut off and I can't scroll down any further.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<ScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/VVV"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:fillViewport="true"
    >


    <android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout
        android:id="@+id/testLayout"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">


        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/text1"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="@string/large_text"
            app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/testImg"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:adjustViewBounds="true"
            android:src="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
            app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/text1" />


    </android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
</ScrollView>
```

This is the java code for it:

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);



    ConstraintSet set = new ConstraintSet();

    ImageView imageView1 = new ImageView(this);

    imageView1.setImageResource(R.mipmap.ic_launcher_round);


    TextView textView = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.text1);

    int imgId = 100+1;

    imageView1.setId(imgId);

    imageView1.setAdjustViewBounds(true);

    ConstraintLayout layout = (ConstraintLayout) findViewById(R.id.testLayout);

    layout.addView(imageView1);

    set.clone(layout);

    set.connect(imgId, ConstraintSet.TOP, textView.getId(),ConstraintSet.BOTTOM);

    set.connect(imgId, ConstraintSet.LEFT, PARENT_ID,ConstraintSet.LEFT);

    set.connect(imgId, ConstraintSet.RIGHT, PARENT_ID,ConstraintSet.RIGHT);

    set.constrainWidth(imgId,ConstraintSet.MATCH_CONSTRAINT);

    set.constrainHeight(imgId, ConstraintSet.WRAP_CONTENT);

    set.connect(R.id.testImg, ConstraintSet.TOP, imgId , ConstraintSet.BOTTOM);

    ScrollView scrollView = (ScrollView) findViewById(R.id.VVV);

    scrollView.setFillViewport(true);



    set.applyTo(layout);
```

Here is an image of what is happening at the bottom of the scrollView and it no longer scrolls down.

[image]

I have tried to remove the fillViewport, and I have also tried to change it to add a Linear layout in the the constraint layout to see if its a problem with the constraint layout but it doesn't seem to work.

Comment: Set the ScrollView height - wrap_content and check if that works or not

Comment: I want to suggest you first that in these type of cases go with the `NestedScrollView`. Please check this [https://stackoverflow.com/a/43773621/5343866](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43773621/5343866) may it help you.

Comment: I tried the wrap content and the NestedScrollView and it doesn't do anything, the problem is that this works when I manually add the imageViews but not when I add them through java.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved this problem by wrapping the `ScrollView` in a `ConstraintLayout`and setting the scrollView height and width to `0dp` as this allows it to expand to the size of the constraintLayout and then remove this line `android:fillViewport="true"` and also set the second constraintLayout to `match-parent` for both width and height.

Incase I wasn't clear here is the updated code:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/VVV"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    >


    <ScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
        xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        >

        <android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout
            android:id="@+id/testLayout"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent">


            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/text1"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Pellentesque diam magna, porta vitae est ac, euismod consectetur erat. Sed non risus bibendum, scelerisque ex congue, imperdiet ipsum. Nulla convallis sapien vel semper suscipit. Quisque aliquam elit ut accumsan auctor. Pellentesque pulvinar, sapien gravida faucibus facilisis, odio tellus luctus lacus, eget porttitor orci magna vitae tellus. Morbi sed nulla placerat, laoreet leo mattis, fermentum mauris. Nulla dictum vulputate pharetra. Quisque porttitor convallis vestibulum. Orci varius natoque penatibus et magnis dis parturient montes, nascetur ridiculus mus. Donec sit amet sapien dignissim, malesuada purus a, ultricies sapien.

    Nunc pharetra ante a posuere viverra. Nam feugiat ante ut tellus tincidunt bibendum. In dignissim massa eu diam aliquam tincidunt. Donec ac quam condimentum, fermentum dui feugiat, dictum nunc. Integer placerat et ex sit amet ultrices. Nunc a porta dolor. Suspendisse in risus placerat, semper sem vitae, pretium nulla. Donec fermentum diam eget lacus efficitur scelerisque. Quisque at ipsum at ante fermentum finibus.
    us. Etiam lorem augue, mattis et purus vel, accumsan aliquet mi. Integer in elementum elit. Nullam ornare ex leo, quis volutpat purus ultrices eu. Sed posuere ac tellus venenatis tincidunt. Duis egestas erat dapibus ligula finibus, a commodo enim congue. Nunc elit tellus, sagittis et arcu vel, euismod egestas est."
                app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
                />


            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/testImg"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:adjustViewBounds="true"
                android:src="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
                app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/text1" />


        </android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
    </ScrollView>

</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

and the Java code:

```
    ConstraintSet set = new ConstraintSet();

    ImageView imageView1 = new ImageView(this);


    imageView1.setImageResource(R.drawable.testscreen);


    TextView textView = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.text1);

    int imgId = 100+1;

    imageView1.setId(imgId);

    imageView1.setAdjustViewBounds(true);

    ConstraintLayout layout = (ConstraintLayout) findViewById(R.id.testLayout);

    layout.addView(imageView1);

    set.clone(layout);

    set.connect(imgId, ConstraintSet.TOP, R.id.text1,ConstraintSet.BOTTOM);

    set.connect(imgId, ConstraintSet.LEFT, PARENT_ID,ConstraintSet.LEFT);

    set.connect(imgId, ConstraintSet.RIGHT, PARENT_ID,ConstraintSet.RIGHT);

    set.constrainWidth(imgId,ConstraintSet.MATCH_CONSTRAINT);

    set.constrainHeight(imgId, ConstraintSet.WRAP_CONTENT);

    set.connect(R.id.testImg, ConstraintSet.TOP, imgId , ConstraintSet.BOTTOM);

    set.applyTo(layout);
```

Note this should also work with the NestedScrollView.

Answer (score 0):

You should try nested scroll view as your root layout.

Comment: Switching to a nestedscrollview did nothing as well, it still won't allow me to scroll down

Answer (score 0):

try calling `scrollView.requestLayout()` and `layout.requestLayout()` after adding the imageView.

Comment: This seems to do nothing