# HorizontalScrollView not working with ConstraintLayout when views are placed with constraints

Tags: android, android-constraintlayout, horizontalscrollview

I want to make a Contraintlayout wrapped in HorizontalScrollView like [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mGjmQ.png),
this is the code:

```
    <HorizontalScrollView
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
    android:fillViewport="true">

    <android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:background="@color/black">

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/imageView_dis1"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/imageView_dis2"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
            android:src="@drawable/common_google_signin_btn_icon_dark_normal_background"
            app:layout_constraintDimensionRatio="H,1:1"/>


            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/imageView_dis1_pow1"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="0dp"
                app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="@id/imageView_dis1"
                app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@id/imageView_dis1"
                app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@id/imageView_dis1"
                android:src="@drawable/common_google_signin_btn_icon_dark_normal_background"
                app:layout_constraintDimensionRatio="H,1:1"/>



            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/imageView_dis1_pow2"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="0dp"
                app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="@id/imageView_dis1"
                app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@id/imageView_dis1"
                app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@id/imageView_dis1_pow1"
                android:src="@drawable/common_google_signin_btn_icon_dark_normal_background"
                app:layout_constraintDimensionRatio="H,1:1"/>

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/imageView_dis1_pow3"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="0dp"
                app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="@id/imageView_dis1"
                app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@id/imageView_dis1"
                app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@id/imageView_dis1_pow2"
                android:src="@drawable/common_google_signin_btn_icon_dark_normal_background"
                app:layout_constraintDimensionRatio="H,1:1"/>

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/imageView_dis1_pow4"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="0dp"
                app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="@id/imageView_dis1"
                app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@id/imageView_dis1"
                app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@id/imageView_dis1_pow3"
                android:src="@drawable/common_google_signin_btn_icon_dark_normal_background"
                app:layout_constraintDimensionRatio="H,1:1"/>

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/imageView_dis1_pow5"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="0dp"
                app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="@id/imageView_dis1"
                app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@id/imageView_dis1"
                app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@id/imageView_dis1_pow4"
                android:src="@drawable/common_google_signin_btn_icon_dark_normal_background"
                app:layout_constraintDimensionRatio="H,1:1"/>

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/imageView_dis1_pow6"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="0dp"
                app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="@id/imageView_dis1"
                app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@id/imageView_dis1"
                app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@id/imageView_dis1_pow5"
                android:src="@drawable/common_google_signin_btn_icon_dark_normal_background"
                app:layout_constraintDimensionRatio="H,1:1"/>

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/imageView_dis1_pow7"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="0dp"
                app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="@id/imageView_dis1"
                app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@id/imageView_dis1"
                app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@id/imageView_dis1_pow6"
                android:src="@drawable/common_google_signin_btn_icon_dark_normal_background"
                app:layout_constraintDimensionRatio="H,1:1"/>

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/imageView_dis1_pow8"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="0dp"
                app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="@id/imageView_dis1"
                app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@id/imageView_dis1"
                app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@id/imageView_dis1_pow7"
                android:src="@drawable/common_google_signin_btn_icon_dark_normal_background"
                app:layout_constraintDimensionRatio="H,1:1"/>

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/imageView_dis1_pow9"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="0dp"
                app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="@id/imageView_dis1"
                app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@id/imageView_dis1"
                app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@id/imageView_dis1_pow8"
                android:src="@drawable/common_google_signin_btn_icon_dark_normal_background"
                app:layout_constraintDimensionRatio="H,1:1"/>

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/imageView_dis1_pow10"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="0dp"
                app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="@id/imageView_dis1"
                app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@id/imageView_dis1"
                app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@id/imageView_dis1_pow9"
                android:src="@drawable/common_google_signin_btn_icon_dark_normal_background"
                app:layout_constraintDimensionRatio="H,1:1"/>





        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/imageView_dis2"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/imageView_dis3"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/imageView_dis1"
            android:src="@drawable/common_google_signin_btn_icon_dark_normal_background"
            app:layout_constraintDimensionRatio="H,1:1"  />

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/imageView_dis3"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/imageView_dis4"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/imageView_dis2"
            android:src="@drawable/common_google_signin_btn_icon_dark_normal_background"
            app:layout_constraintDimensionRatio="H,1:1" />

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/imageView_dis4"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/imageView_dis5"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/imageView_dis3"
            android:src="@drawable/common_google_signin_btn_icon_dark_normal_background"
            app:layout_constraintDimensionRatio="H,1:1" />

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/imageView_dis5"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/imageView_dis6"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/imageView_dis4"
            android:src="@drawable/common_google_signin_btn_icon_dark_normal_background"
            app:layout_constraintDimensionRatio="H,1:1" />

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/imageView_dis6"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/imageView_dis7"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/imageView_dis5"
            android:src="@drawable/common_google_signin_btn_icon_dark_normal_background"
            app:layout_constraintDimensionRatio="H,1:1" />

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/imageView_dis7"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/imageView_dis8"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/imageView_dis6"
            android:src="@drawable/common_google_signin_btn_icon_dark_normal_background"
            app:layout_constraintDimensionRatio="H,1:1" />

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/imageView_dis8"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/imageView_dis7"
            android:src="@drawable/common_google_signin_btn_icon_dark_normal_background"
            app:layout_constraintDimensionRatio="H,1:1" />


    </android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
</HorizontalScrollView>
```

But I'm unable to scroll horizontally, the problem apparently occurs when using `app:layout:contraintStart_toEndOf="ImageView"` to place images horizontally, if I just place a `LinearLayout` it works as expected.
Any idea why is this happening? I'm using constraint layout 1.1.0

Comment: I tried your and code and modified it. But the modified code does not show the complete vertical row, to view you need to scroll vertically. Is it ok?

Answer (score 0):

I tested the above example and came to the conclusion, that horizontal scrolling does not work if you have full vertical constraints in child views from parent top to parent bottom.

If you remove `app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf` from `@+id/imageView_dis8` or set a fixed width (or height, as the `layout_constraintDimensionRatio`is set) to `@+id/imageView_dis1` horizontal scrolling works again - although your complete layout is then distorted.

This observation was obviously also done [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48299530/9562605)