# How do i use a scrollview?

Tags: android, user-interface, scrollview

I want to put a scroll view to scroll the content on my screen, but I can't understand what I'm doing wrong here. Any help would be highly appreciated. Do I need to put my constraint layout in a linear layout and then that linear view in the scroll view or I'm doing something else wrong here?

```
 <ScrollView
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:fillViewport="true">

        <android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content">

            <android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout
                android:id="@+id/layout_fragment_head"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="0dp"
                android:background="@color/color_theme_main_dark"
                app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/guideline15"
                app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent">

                // I edited the code here for simplicity

            </android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>

            <fragment
                android:id="@+id/fragment_deviceslist"
                android:name="com.resatech.android.scoutandroid.master.fragments.DevicesListFragment"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="0dp"
                app:defaultNavHost="true"
                app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"
                app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@+id/guideline15"
                tools:layout="@layout/fragment_devices_list" />

            <android.support.constraint.Guideline
                android:id="@+id/guideline15"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:orientation="horizontal"
                app:layout_constraintGuide_percent=".3" />


            </android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>

         </ScrollView>
```

Comment: You might want to have a look at this, since constraint layouts inside scroll views seem to present some difficulties: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37349845/is-it-possible-to-put-a-constraintlayout-inside-a-scrollview

Comment: I did but still no help :/

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Android - how to make a scrollable constraintlayout?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43098150/android-how-to-make-a-scrollable-constraintlayout)

Comment: scrollView should contain only one child View, otherwise use Nested ScrollView

Answer (score 1):

You should not put a `ConstraintLayout` inside a `ScrollView`. Otherwise, objects inside `ConstraintLayout` cannot scroll because they are constrained.

Put the `ScrollView` inside the `ConstraintLayout`, then, all objects inside `ScrollView` can be scrolled (because they are not constrained).
In this case, the only constrained view is the `ScrollView` and this is correct.

If you want a fixed header, put it outside the `ScrollView` constrained to top of the `ConstraintLayout`.

Comment: if i do that.. It just gives the error the Scrollview can only contain one direct child.

Comment: Yes, the `ScrollView` should contain only the fragment and the header outside the `ScrollView`. Of course, the `GuideLine` outside the ScrollView too.

Answer (score 0):

in `ScrollView` just add one layer! 
To fix your problem edit your code like this :

```
<ScrollView
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:fillViewport="true">

        <RelativeLayout
           android:layout_width="match_parent"
           android:layout_height="match_parent">

                /* Your Code of Constraint Layout Like :
                <RelativeLayout />
                <ImageView />
                <LinerLayout/>
                and ....  */

        </RelativeLayout>

</ScrollView>
```

Comment: you should explain your answer more - why can't you add more layouts inside scrollview?

Comment: So are u suggesting that i should put my constraint layout in that relative layout ?

Comment: @kkarakk body of scrollview just can support one child for avoid disruption! and you can write other your layout in child layout

Comment: @MuhammadAbdullah no! you just need change your first ConstraintLayout to RelativeLayout

Comment: @hmotamed I did that and i just got a blank layout now ?

Comment: @MuhammadAbdullah no after this work your error fixed!!!! maybe forget close layout or write your design layout!