# why can't i access the field which are not in the constraint layout frame

Tags: android, android-layout, constraints

[This shows the app image in which the button is below the confirm password](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zKyGh.png)

i want to access the button which is below the confirm password field but this constraint layout is not scrollablr so i can't access the fields which are not fitting in fram

Comment: put your contsraint layout inside nestedScrollView or ScrollView

Answer (score 1):

It is necessary to have an ScrollView.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<ScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">

     <!-- your code -->

</ScrollView>
```

[Android - how to make a scrollable constraintlayout?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43098150/android-how-to-make-a-scrollable-constraintlayout?rq=1)