# How can I scroll vertically the ConstraintLayout?

Tags: android, android-scrollview, android-constraintlayout

### The content of the main activity looks like:

the main screen looks like (all this inside ConstraintLayout):

- image title
- date
- the image itself
- image description

The image description may be too long to be displayed, to fix this I can put it inside a ScrollView, and this works just fine. However, I would like to ScrollView the whole ConstraintLayout, and this is not functioning properly: cannot scroll and some TextViews do not appear!

---

### Relevant Code:

```
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout  
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/desciptionScroll"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"
    tools:context="com.picture.nasa.nasadailyimage.NasaDailyImage"
    tools:showIn="@layout/activity_nasa_daily_image">

 <TextView
    android:id="@+id/imageTitle"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginLeft="8dp"
    android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
    android:text="@string/test_image_title"
    app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

 <TextView
    android:id="@+id/imageDate"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginLeft="8dp"
    android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
    android:text="@string/test_image_date"
    app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/imageTitle" />

 <ImageView
    android:id="@+id/imageDisplay"
    android:layout_width="368dp"
    android:layout_height="408dp"
    android:layout_marginLeft="8dp"
    android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="3dp"
    android:src="@mipmap/test_image"
    app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/imageDate" />

<TextView 
    android:id="@+id/imageDescription"
    android:layout_width="368dp"
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    android:layout_marginLeft="8dp" 
    android:layout_marginStart="8dp" 
    android:layout_marginTop="4dp" 
    android:text="@string/test_image_description" 
    app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent" 
    app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/imageDisplay" />

</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

Answer (score 17, accepted):

For making the elements in the screen scrollable I think you could use a NestedScrollView inside a CoordinatorLayout.
I usually put a LinearLayout with all the elements I would display there.

For example:

```
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context="com.xengar.android.puzzlewildanimals.ui.HelpActivity">

    <android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme.AppBarOverlay">

        <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
            android:id="@+id/toolbar"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
            android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
            app:popupTheme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark" />

    </android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>

    <android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior">

        <android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout  
        xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
        xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
            android:id="@+id/desciptionScroll"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            tools:context="com.picture.nasa.nasadailyimage.NasaDailyImage"
            tools:showIn="@layout/activity_nasa_daily_image">


            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/imageTitle"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginLeft="8dp"
                android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
                android:text="@string/test_image_title"
                app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/imageDate"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginLeft="8dp"
                android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
                android:text="@string/test_image_date"
                app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/imageTitle" />

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/imageDisplay"
                android:layout_width="368dp"
                android:layout_height="408dp"
                android:layout_marginLeft="8dp"
                android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="3dp"
                android:src="@mipmap/test_image"
                app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/imageDate" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/imageDescription"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginLeft="8dp"
                android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="4dp"
                android:text="@string/test_image_description"
                app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/imageDisplay" />




        </android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
    </android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView>

</android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

If that doesn't work you can replace the ConstraintLayout with a LinearLayout.
I hope that helps.

Comment: i can scroll the textview or any number of textviews together. the whole point of the question is: how can i scroll the constraintlayout as a whole

Comment: Maybe by putting the ConstraintLayout inside the NestedScrollView.

Comment: I just edited my response. My suggestion is to use a NestedScrollView an inside that put all elements that would be scrollable.

Comment: i tried to put a very long title in order to test if the scroller works and it did! it works. However the image description does not appear. do you have any idea why?

Comment: Besides the scrolling, it looks you're using the ConstraintLayout as a container for the TextView's and ImageView.   If you use a NestedScrollView for the scrolling, then you just need a container for that. I usually use a LinearLayout for just containing all that.

Comment: For the imageDescription it looks you set the size like: android:layout_width="368dp"
        android:layout_height="0dp"    Maybe if you put it according to the string size like the others   android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"

Comment: thanks alot!
wrap_content for the image description (height) did the trick. but i don't fully understand how this solved the problem! is it because i bounded the height of the description so it won't surpass the screen?

Comment: What "wrap_content" do is resize the height according to the string size. So, the TextView is growing or contracting according to what the string needs. That's useful if the text changes like by code.   You're welcome :)

Answer (score 2):

To add scrolling to any view, you add a ScrollView. In your code, add it as the root(If the ScrolLView isn't the root and there is more content, add the ScrollView around the ConstraintLayout). move the namespaces(lines containing `xmlns`) to the new root. Add width and height in the ScrollView to match_parent(or whatever you have) and set the height of the ConstraintLayout to wrap_content.

However, you will not be able to scroll correctly in design mode. ([reference](https://stackoverflow.com/q/39689495/6296561)). But it will still work as ecpected on a device.

### **NOTE:**

If your layout doesn't scroll with a SCrollView, make sure you set the **height** of the **ConstraintLayout** to **wrap_content**

Comment: still does not work:
there is no scroller and the title, date and description do not appear!

Answer (score 0):

No need to use a `NestedScrollView` as long as you can get the constraint layout to "extend" beyond its ScrollView parent as described [in this related SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57791934/1145905)

Answer (score -1):

surrounded my constrinat-layout with a ScrollView tag and gave it the property `android:isScrollContainer="true"`.